# column layout in R Presentation

Tags: r, rstudio, rpres

I'd like to have two columns on a slide in R Presentation, with the column-split after a full-width paragraph, but I can only get this:

[image: ice cream columns]

I want the "Ice Cream" section to take up the full width of the slide, and the "Ben's Ice Cream Palace" and "Jerry's Ice Cream Castle" sections to appear next to each other below that. Changing the level of the section headings doesn't seem to have any effect. Is there a way to do this?

```
Troubleshooting
========================================================

## Ice Cream

My town has two ice-cream parlours, Ben's Ice Cream Palace and Jerry's Ice Cream Castle. It would be nice to show the two establishments' flavours side-by-side so that we could compare them easily when deciding where to go buy ice cream on a hot sunny day.

### Ben's Ice Cream Palace
- Chocolate
- Vanilla
- Neopolitan
- Rum Raisin
- Butter Pecan
- Mint Chocolate Chip

***

### Jerry's Ice Cream Castle
- Chocolate
- Vanilla
- Strawberry
- Chunky Monkey
- Chocolate Chip Cookie Dough
```

Comment: One possibility is to put the lists into adjacent cells of a table. This is an old HTML hack that will probably work.

Comment: An old answer, but it wasn't possible in 2014: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/201293496-Header-on-two-column-layout-R-presentation